# Scrolling through tabs in Firefox without opening them

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys, tabs, navigation

[image]

When we have many tabs open in Firefox we get one arrow on each side to scroll through the tabs. What I usually do is to use the mouse (yuck!) to click on those arrows to do the scrolling. How can I achieve the same behavior using the keyboard?

Now I know we can use shortcuts to scroll through tabs by opening them, for example with <kbd>Ctrl+PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+PgDn</kbd>. However, this implies opening the tab and I do not want to do that. I have multiple groups of tabs with a few of them containing dozens of tabs. When I close Firefox and come back they do not load automatically. So if I'm in a tab in position 57 and want to go to a tab in position 33 by using <kbd>Ctrl+PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+PgDn</kbd> then all tabs in between are loaded. When I use the arrows instead the tabs do not load and the tab which has the focus is still open although it is not currently showing on the tab bar. In the end, the final tab selection would still have to be done using the mouse but it would be convenient to do the scrolling with the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, I've got the exact same problem and my workaround (not a solution) is: keep the most important tabs in the first 9 and use [Alt][1] to [9] to to those to use the mouse wheel...  Hover over any tab and roll the mouse wheel and click (as I'm handling the mouse anyway). Shitty, but less shitty then opening 25 tabs with [Ctrl][PgDn]...  If this is good enough for you, I can convert it to an answer... **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: I already do this in a different computer but unfortunately it doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: ;-)  That's why this is a comment, rather then the answers below!  Your choice!  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use **Alt+ Numbers**.

For example, *Alt+1* to go to the first page, *Alt+6* to go to the 6th page, etc. But this shortcut works only when less than 9 tabs are opened.

For managing a lot of tabs consider using **Tabs Menu** extension. Once it is installed you can go to menubar by pressing Alt+F10, and there will be **tabs** menu with the list of all opened tabs.

[image: Screenshot from makeuseof.com]

See here also: [Makeuseof review](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/organize-firefox-with-these-superb-tab-management-tools/)

Comment: Alt+19 sends me to the first tab and then to the last one. I believe this shortcut is limited to tabs 1–8 and Alt+9 takes you to the last tab.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I am editing my answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to bring up a view of all tabs. Select desired tab from the ones shown

[image]

Comment: This only works if you have a little amount of tabs open. Ctrl+Shift+E shows the groups screen. Since I have over a dozen groups these end up being small squares, one per group, with tabs stacked up in each group.